# Laravel passport change header authentication

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel passport and it requires to send in every request the header Authentication to be sent.

Is it possible to change the name of the header to X-Access-Token?

I saw passport uses the package

> League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators;

method:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validateAuthorization(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    dd($request);
    if ($request->hasHeader('authorization') === false) {
        throw OAuthServerException::accessDenied('Missing "Authorization" header');
    }

    $header = $request->getHeader('authorization');
    $jwt = trim(preg_replace('/^(?:\s+)?Bearer\s/', '', $header[0]));
```

I tried to change here but seems the validation of the headers happen before this method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many fundamental pieces of code that rely on the existence of the `authorization` header.

You could roll your own if you felt so inclined.

Note also that `authorization` is a **web standard** request header. X-Access-Token is a `response header` pattern.

*Edit**
Given our conversation below, you can use Middleware and Middleware priority to dictate which runs first, observe requests that have an `X-Access-Token` and use `addHeader` to convert the value of that header to `authorization`:

```
php artisan make:middleware AuthorizationToolMiddleware
```

Then in the `handle` function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $request->headers->set('Authorization', $request->headers->get('X-Access-Token'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

This middleware should execute before other middleware in order to ensure the headers are set by the time that passport handles the request.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do not have idea where and how to start to search.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione It would be too much work to attempt to do this while using Passport, which relies heavily on the League2/Oauth package. Instead, I would recommend trying to figure out why it's necessary to make this change and re-thinking whether or not it's really necessary before heading down this path.

Comment: I agree with you about the complexity. I built an api service that need to be test with an automatic tool that requires the header name X-access-token. Otherwise it fails. And this api service I built is for a test to be hired

Comment: Why not just also send `X-Access-Token` along with `Authorization`? Seems like it would work

Comment: The problem is that the test tool send http request

Comment: @StefanoMaglione I've given a possible solution, I can't test it, but it might work for you

Comment: I added the middleware but unfortunately I still receive {"error":"Unauthenticated.","code":401}.

Comment: It seems it is executed after the check on the header. I put a dd before the header set and it is already error auth

Comment: Ok seems I need to understand how to set middleware priority

Comment: Great soultion, it works. There was a small error and I fixed like this: $request->headers->set('Authorization', $request->headers->get('X-Access-Token'));

    return $next($request);

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.8 you'd have to force your custom middleware to always be on top of the call chain
So in your `app\kernel.php` add this -

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AuthorizationToolMiddleware::class,
    ];
```